# JComboBox erases the JComponent over which it pops up

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jcomponent

I am working on a program that will function similarly to Paint. It looks like this: [program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvvOt.png)

The error occurs when I open the JComboBox(used to select brush size). It seems to erase whatever has been drawn under it. 
[JComboBox opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdLmc.png). After closing the JComboBox it looks like this: [JComboBox closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwdv3.png)

Any ideas as to what might be causing this, and how to remedy it?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Paint extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel topBar;
    private JComboBox<String> brushSizes;
    private DrawArea drawArea;

    public Paint() throws IOException {
        setTitle("Paint");
        setSize(500,500);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        drawArea = new DrawArea();
        topBar = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        String[] sizes = {"1", "2", "3", "5", "8", "10", "25", "50", "100"};
        brushSizes = new JComboBox<String>(sizes);
        brushSizes.setSelectedIndex(0);
        brushSizes.setActionCommand("BrushSize");
        brushSizes.addActionListener(this);
        topBar.add(brushSizes);
        add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("BrushSize")) {
            drawArea.setBrushStroke(Integer.parseInt((String)brushSizes.getSelectedItem()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
    }
}
```

More Code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawArea extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener,     MouseListener {
    private Color currentColor;
    private boolean dragging;
    private int toX;
    private int toY;
    private int brushSize;
    private Graphics drawer;

    public DrawArea() {
        currentColor = Color.BLACK;
        dragging = false;
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        toX = -1;
        toY = -1;
        brushSize = 1;
        repaint();
    }

    public void setBrushStroke(int size) {
        brushSize = size;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);
        g.setColor(currentColor);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        dragging = true;
        toX = event.getX();
        toY = event.getY();
        drawer = getGraphics();
        drawer.setColor(currentColor);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        dragging = false;
        drawer.dispose();
        drawer = null;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        if (dragging) {
            int x = event.getX();
            int y = event.getY();

            Graphics2D drawerTo = (Graphics2D) drawer;
            drawerTo.setStroke(new BasicStroke(brushSize));
            drawerTo.drawLine(toX, toY, x, y);
            toX = x;
            toY = y;
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {}
}
```

Comment: Without code, we can only guess.  Try removing parts of your program other than the painting and JComboBox in order to create a [mcve].  (My best guess is that your paintComponent method is not calling `super.paintComponent` like it’s supposed to.)

Comment: An MCVE as suggested by @VGR should be something we can copy/paste, compile & run to see the problem! As such, code like  `Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("ColorButtons.txt"));` should **not** be included in one. Firstly, is it really relevant to the problem? Secondly, if so, those .. colors(?) should be hard coded in the MCVE.

Comment: Sorry for this transgression. I have simplified the program to be an MCVE

Comment: 1) `private Graphics drawer;` Don't try to cache a `Graphics` instance. They are transitory. This is the source of the problem in the code. Instead hold variables (such as `Color` etc,) as attributes of the class that can be changed in one method (e.g. on mouse press) and accessed in another (e.g. paint component). Call `repaint()` to invoke a repaint (which will trickle down to paint component).  2) Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: If you want to paint using a saved Graphics object, check out the `DrawOnImage` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example on how to paint to a `BufferedImage` using its Graphics object. Otherwise all the custom painting needs to be in the paintComponent() method using the Graphics object passed to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways to do custom painting. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for examples of each approach:

1. The `DrawOnImage` example shows how to paint to a `BufferedImage` using the `Graphics` object of the `BufferedImage`.
2. The `DrawOnComponent` example shows how to use the `Graphics` object passed to the `paintComponent(...)` method of the component.

The approach you use will depend on your exact requirement.